# Why should I avoid the a4 and aeguill packages?

Tags: fonts, packages, paper-size, obsolete

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89707/9179) answer am I being told, that I shouldn't use the `a4` and the `aeguill` packages.

Why should I do that, and what should I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regard to `a4`, a quote from the [english version](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) of `l2tabu` will do:

> 1.1 *a4.sty, a4wide.sty*
>
> Do not use these ‘two’ packages any longer. You should delete them
>   without replacement from your LaTeX source. Use the class option
>   `a4paper` instead. Speaking in terms of typography these packages, or
>   others similar to these do not provide good layout. What is even
>   worse, there is more than one version of these packages around, and
>   different versions of those packages are incompatible with one
>   another, providing deviating settings for page margins. So you may not
>   trust that your document will look the same—or just as bad? – when
>   being compiled on someone else’s system when exchanging LaTeX source.
>
> Replace: *a4.sty*, or *a4wide.sty* by class option `a4paper`

For `aeguill`, see Philippe Goutet' s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5901/510) to [Are ae and aeguill only needed when using CM fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/are-ae-and-aeguill-only-needed-when-using-cm-fonts)

Comment: If I remove the `\usepackage{a4}` then the margins become larger, even when I use class option `a4paper`. How do I know which margin layout is "correct"?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting There's no "correct" layout, but there are better and worse ones. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big

Comment: If I remove `\usepackage{aeguill}` then are the bottom of all letters cut off. My tex file is the one I linked to in the OP.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Might be a problem of your document class. Please edit your original question and include the additional information.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting I suppose you want to use the german margins. The easiest way to achieve them is to use the KOMA script classes like scrartcl which have a wider layout by default